# WSO2ESB for each mediator, FOR EACH RESPONSE having /n/t extra with each element

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have this below mentioned soap request, I am using `WSO2ESB 4.9`.
Soap request :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><jsonArray><jsonElement><a><s>as</s></a><b>Type1</b><c>C1</c><d><t>A1</t></d><e>e1</e></jsonElement><jsonElement><a><s>as</s></a><b>Type2</b><c>C2</c><d><t>A1</t></d><e>e1</e></jsonElement></jsonArray></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to iterator over jsonElement/b and get json list : `["Type1", "Type2"]`.But I am getting below list :

```
[
  "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tType1\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t",
  "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tType2\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"
]
```

Please any way to get the required list.For each mediator :

```
<foreach expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement">
    <sequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <jsonElement>
                    $1
                </jsonElement>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg expression="//b" evaluator="xml" />
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, there is space and newline in `foreach <jsonElement>`.

Working code:

```
<foreach expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement">
    <sequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <jsonElement xmlns="">$1</jsonElement>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg expression="//b" evaluator="xml" />
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
    </sequence>
</foreach>
```